# whats wrong in this equation

Tags: equations

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:42}
 E_t(k,d)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} k * E_{ele} + k * E_{fs} * d^2 \mbox{~ if} d< d_0 , \\  k * E_{ele} + k * E_{mp} * d^4 \mbox{~ if} d\geq d_0
 \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I am getting error as ! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode.
\endequation ->\eqno 
                     \hbox {\@eqnnum }$$\@ignoretrue 
l.80 \end{equation}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you use `\left`, you also need to use `\right`. Try adding `\right.` after `\edn{array}` (mind the dot).

Answer (score 5):

There are many things wrong, I'm afraid.

The main error is about TeX syntax: a `\left` command must have a corresponding `\right` one, in this case `\right.`, since you don't want a right fence.

On the other hand, the output is not really pretty

[image]

Let's try to correct it.

1. You should load `amsmath` and use its `cases` environment.
2. Multiplication is *never* denoted with an asterisk in math.
3. Textual subscripts should be upright.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:42}
 E_t(k,d)=
\begin{cases}
k E_{\mathrm{ele}} + k E_{\mathrm{fs}} d^2 & \text{if } d< d_0 , \\
k E_{\mathrm{ele}} + k E_{\mathrm{mp}} d^4 & \text{if } d\geq d_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It lacks a `\right.` to close the `\left\{`. See the code below:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:42}
 E_t(k,d)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} k * E_{ele} + k * E_{fs} * d^2 \mbox{~ if} d< d_0 , \\  k * E_{ele} + k * E_{mp} * d^4 \mbox{~ if} d\geq d_0
 \end{array}\right. %<-- this one was missing
\end{equation}
```

Another alternative is use `cases` from `amsmath` package:

```
\begin{equation}
 E_t(k,d)=\begin{cases}
 k * E_{ele} + k * E_{fs} * d^2  & \mbox{~ if} d< d_0 , \\
 k * E_{ele} + k * E_{mp} * d^4 & \mbox{~ if} d\geq d_0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

I add a MWE with both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:42}
 E_t(k,d)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} k * E_{ele} + k * E_{fs} * d^2 \mbox{~ if} d< d_0 , \\  k * E_{ele} + k * E_{mp} * d^4 \mbox{~ if} d\geq d_0
 \end{array}\right. %<-- this one was missing
\end{equation}

\medskip

\begin{equation}
 E_t(k,d)=\begin{cases}
 k * E_{ele} + k * E_{fs} * d^2  & \mbox{~ if} d< d_0 , \\
 k * E_{ele} + k * E_{mp} * d^4 & \mbox{~ if} d\geq d_0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: thank you but still I am getting error

Comment: @Mrinai Did you load `amsmath`?

Comment: I dont want \right\}

Comment: @Mrinai of course not is `\right.` note the dot after `\right`. This dot is used to "close" the opened `\left\{`

Comment: @Mrinai I have added a MWE to be sure that the code is compilable

Comment: Thank you am able to compile correctly

Comment: @Mrinai That’s good!